# How to fix vmodel selected option vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

So I have a web app where the user chooses from a list of options. Look at the following code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <select v-model="étatArticle" class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Indique l'état de ton article</option>
        <option value="neuf">Neuf</option>
        <option value=tresBon>Trés bon état</option>
        <option value="bon">Bon état</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The problem is is that the v-model is causing the first selected option to disappear. to understand what I'm saying , look at the following images.

[With v-model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEQuZ.png)

Without v-model I get this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehPBT.png)

can you please help me fix that? thank you.

Comment: You can't have selected attribute here, Vue is taking care of that through v-model. You should see  a warning in console. Remove selected and then check it out.

Comment: i still cannot see the first option !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  template: '#main',
  data:
  {
    etatArticle: null
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<template id="main">
<div class="form-group">
    <select v-model="etatArticle" class="form-control">
        <option :value="null" disabled selected>Indique l'état de ton article</option>
        <option value="neuf">Neuf</option>
        <option value=tresBon>Trés bon état</option>
        <option value="bon">Bon état</option>
    </select>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: even though it worked here i still don't understand why it's not working in my app ! (i'm using vue 3 + nuxt). maybe it has to do with the version i'm currently using ?

Comment: Your app does not set the initial value of the model variable - so it is NULL but the value of the first option (the disabled one) is not NULL, it is an empty string. So there is no match and thus no option is preselected.

Answer (score 1):

In your component data, you need to define the default value of your v-model. You can see example in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-demo-1-cx691?file=/src/components/CustomComponent.vue).

In your template:

```
<select v-model="selectedValue" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected>
      Disabled and selected by default
    </option>
    <option value="first">First</option>
    <option value="second">Second</option>
    <option value="third">Third</option>
  </select>
```

In your data:

```
  data() {
    return {
      // Define your value by default to show it
      selectedValue: "",
    };
  },
```